За что отвечает оператор `^` в C#?
Недавно столкнулся со следующим выражением:
.Aggregate(0, (val1, val2) => val1 ^ val2.GetHashCode()))
Подскажите пожалуйста, что делает в данном случаи этот оператор - ^?

Рассмотрите HashCode.Combine. или HashCode.Add, вместо этой конструкции

оператор XOR  - представляет собой побитовую операцию (^ "исключающее или")
может быть полезно для получения уникальных результатов при объединении данных, как, например, в случае хеширования
Выражение .Aggregate(0, (val1, val2) => val1 ^ val2.GetHashCode()) объединяет хеш-коды всех элементов в коллекции в один итоговый хеш-код, используя XOR, начиная с начального значения 0

Это xor - побитовое исключающее или.
В данном случае использован как один из простейших способов объединять хэшкоды без переполнения.
